# How to run a React demo as quickly as Vue does?

Tags: reactjs, vue.js

Somethimes, I need to run a demo as conveniently as possible

for Vue, use vue-cli, that can simply servers a single file, for example, App.vue, when run `vue serve App.vue`, it works

But for React, can I run a demo as quickly as Vue?

Comment: What do you mean by "run a demo as conveniently as possible"?

Comment: `create-react-app` might be what you're looking for: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app

Comment: create-react-app is definitely not as simple as vue-cli's `vue serve`

Comment: vue-cli comes with state management and router out of the box so yes doing demos with vue-cli is definitely faster, you need to manually set Redux and React Router if you need them for a demo

Comment: I mean, if you have used vue-cli, we can write a demo just use a single file `App.vue`, vue-cli will config for everything I need, but for React, `create-react-app` is too large, and is not as simple as Vue I think. Just write a demo, nothing more, `create-react-app` is too heavy for me